# Flutter Mobx @observable is not rebuilding

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, mobx

I am new to flutter and trying to create simple todo app using mobx.
whenever I am adding a new task I can see new updated tasks data in my @action but it is not reflecting on UI.

main.dart

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<TaskList>(
      create: (content) => TaskList(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

taskList

```
@observable
  List<Task> tasksList = [
    Task(name: 'buy milk'),
    Task(name: 'buy sugar'),
    Task(name: 'buy bread'),
  ];

@action
  void addTask(String title) {
    final task = Task(name: title);
    tasksList.add(task);
    print(tasksList);
  }
```

TodoApp class

```
class TodoApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget buildBottomSheet(BuildContext context) {
    return AddTaskScreen();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Provider<TaskList>(
    create: (_) => TaskList(),
    child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Todos'),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            //isScrollControlled: true,
            builder: buildBottomSheet,
          );
        },
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TodoListView(),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

TodoListView class

```
class TodoListView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final list = Provider.of<TaskList>(context);

    return Observer(
      builder: (_) => Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (content, index) {
            return Observer(
              builder: (_) => TaskTile(
                taskTitle: list.tasksList[index].name,
                isChecked: list.tasksList[index].isDone,
                checkBoxCallback: (checkBoxState) {
                  // taskData.updateTask(task);
                },
                longPressCallBack: () {
                  list.deleteTask(index);
                },
              ),
            );
          },
          itemCount: list.tasksList.length,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

TaskTile Class

```
class TaskTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String taskTitle;
  final bool isChecked;
  final Function checkBoxCallback;
  final Function longPressCallBack;

  TaskTile(
      {this.taskTitle,
      this.isChecked,
      this.checkBoxCallback,
      this.longPressCallBack});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('task tile');
    print(taskTitle);
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(
        taskTitle,
        style: TextStyle(
          decoration: isChecked ? TextDecoration.lineThrough : null,
        ),
      ),
      trailing: Checkbox(
        activeColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        value: isChecked,
        onChanged: checkBoxCallback,
      ),
      onLongPress: longPressCallBack,
    );
  }
}
```

AddTaskScreen Class

```
class AddTaskScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String newTaskTitle;
    final list = Provider.of<TaskList>(context);

    return Container(
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, top: 20.0, right: 20.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topRight: Radius.circular(20.0), topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0)),
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Add a Task',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 30.0,
                color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
              ),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            TextField(
              autofocus: true,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              onChanged: (newTask) {
                newTaskTitle = newTask;
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20.0,
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text(
                'Add',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
              onPressed: () {
                list.addTask(newTaskTitle);
                Navigator.pop(context);
//                print('piyuhs');
//                print(list);
              },
              color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

in `addTask` action value is updating but it is not reflecting on UI. I know I am doing silly mistake here.
I have search on google also but still not working.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

It's a particular case of mobx indeed.

Actually the notification is fire to the UI when there is a change of **instance** not only parameter.

Here the list is the same instance and doesn't not trigger UI.

To work around this problem you have to make your list an `ObservableList` :

```
  @observable
  ObservableList<Task> tasksList = ObservableList<Task>([  //Change here
    Task(name: 'buy milk'),
    Task(name: 'buy sugar'),
    Task(name: 'buy bread'),
  ]);

  @action
  void addTask(String title) {
    final task = Task(name: title);
    tasksList.add(task);
    print(tasksList);
  }
```

It should do the job ;)